# RSA decryption strips leading null-bytes

Tags: python, rsa, pycrypto

Why does this code:

```
s = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00id\x00\x00"
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util import randpool
key = RSA.generate(1024, randpool.RandomPool().get_bytes)
d = key.encrypt(s, None)
dec = key.decrypt(d)
print ''.join( [ "%02X " % ord( x ) for x in dec ] ).strip()
```

output:

```
03 00 00 00 69 64 00 00
```

instead of

```
00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 69 64 00 00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because the default encryption algorithm adds some leading null-bytes to the message and the decryption algorithm strips all the leading null-bytes even if they were in the original message.

The solution is to use Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP for encryption/decryption.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util import randpool
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP as PKCS


s = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00id\x00\x00"
key = RSA.generate(1024, randpool.RandomPool().get_bytes)

cipher = PKCS.new(key)
encr = cipher.encrypt(s)
decr = cipher.decrypt(encr)
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, but could you please replace PKCS1_v1_5 with PKCS1_OAEP? The effect is the same, but you don't encourage anyone to use a broken encryption scheme.

Comment: I can't edit because there have to be at least 6 characters changed. In Python 3 you need to add `b` before "\x00\x00\x00...".